# Where is the Open Source repository for Swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, open-source

Apple announced Swift becoming Open Source since now two weeks and in his web site https://developer.apple.com/swift, no information was provided to find repository, documentation or Linux implementation announced at WWDC.

Someone have information about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have read it carefully it clearly says that it will be released later this year. So you will find no repository yet

> Open Source Later this year Swift will be released as open source.
>   Swift’s unique combination of elegance, power, and safety has the
>   opportunity to move the entire software industry forward. It is
>   exciting to imagine what we will build together

Late year update:

**www.swift.org**

Comment: question is when it is becoming open source?

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/apple/swift.